# VueJS Process complete template before operations

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Good afternoon.

I have an interesting problem at the moment. We have a third party server that offer translations for static html content. I need to fetch this content via Ajax and display it in my Vue components.

**The current situation**
These translations are fetched via a dictionary-like data structure, i.e. via a category and a key. We have incorporated a Vue plugin to load these into our components via a function `t`, like this:

```html
<template>
    <section>
        <h1>{{ t('CommonHeaders', 'HomePage') }}</h1>
        <p v-html="t('Articles', 'SiteDescription')"></p>
    </section>
</template>
```

At the moment these translations are shipped to the browser by embedding them in the HTML, after which our client-side hydration mechanism reads them and adds them to the Vuex store. The `t` function then looks up the translations and displays them where needed. These translations are reactive and accept data parameters to format translations.

We use Vue SFC to render user flows in an SPA-like fashion, although the site is not yet an SPA.

**The problem**
In order for this to work the translations required for a page have to be listed in the back-end controller methods in a dictionary. 
This has become un-maintainable and much more data is shipped to the front-end than what is necessary. Additionally, the back-end system has no definitive end-point when a page is built before being shipped to the browser that we can hook into in order to add the translations to the HTML and content often end up being duplicated.
The back-end system was built using DotNet MVC 4, so we have no SSR capabilities at this point.

**The solution (hopefully)**
In order to better maintain our code I would like to utilise the 't' function from the plugin to load translations via an AJAX call before the vue engine has rendered the template, i.e. via the *beforeCreate* or *created* hook. The problem is that the Vue instance will have to know about translations required in child component templates before the AJAX call can be fired, and I have no idea how to accomplish this.

***On a side note**, delaying rendering like this goes against all my instincts but it doesn't look like we have a choice at this point. 

I am planning to cache the translations client side with a content hash in case they get updated, so the ajax calls will hopefully not be required very often, only on first load.

The site is gradually being converted into an SPA, at which point I will be able to split off the FE and utilise SSR via node. Up until that point though this is the best idea I could come up with.*

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been thinking about this my self as at the moment I just send an entire cached json to the client on App Init with a loading screen, is not bad at the moment since there is not a lot to translate but was considering the following approach otherwise:

Have an array in the translation vuex module store a list of keys that need to `translate` (array).

Have `t()` push the keys to `translate` if not already in **translated** store and return either **empty string** or a **placeholder** until the translation is re-actively available.

On `mounted` dispatch a `fetch` method on the store to perform the ajax call and set the translation state and clear out the `translate` list when complete.

Vue should by default it's behavior re-render upon the VUEX state being changed and cause `t()` in the template body to be recalled and return matching values on `nextTick` instead of `placeholder` value previously returned.

Comment: This is more or less along the lines I was thinking. But my problem is that I don't necessarily want to send a dispatch a `fetch` method in the mounted hook on each component, but would like to group all the translations needed for all components in a single request. This is on initial load only, any components loaded asynchronously afterwards will have to do an additional `fetch`.

Comment: In that case just place the ajax call in a `setTimeout`, call `clearTimeout` first each time `fetch` is `dispatched` so rapid calls to `fetch` from multiple components cancel out the request until the application settles. This wil give you an effective buffer to allow a larger list of keys to build before making a final `ajax` request.